# Core Data: bundle.main.url returning NIL unexpectedly (and suddenly)

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

The default core data code is throwing an error for some reason.  This just started happening after I attempted to migrate to a new version of the data model, so I'm sure I did something to screw this up.  Here's the relevant code:

```
enter colazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Band_Manager_2_0", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
}()
```

The line throwing the error is this one:

```
enter let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Band_Manager_2_0", withExtension: "momd")!code here
```

And here is the error:

```
    fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-04-21 14:17:01.620046-0400 Band Manager 2.0[5826:164435] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Current stack trace:
0    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000100425160 swift_reportError + 129
1    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000100441b80 _swift_stdlib_reportFatalError + 60
2    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000100231a00 specialized specialized StaticString.withUTF8Buffer<A> ((UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) -> A) -> A + 342
3    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001003acec0 partial apply for (_fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, file : StaticString, line : UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never).(closure #2) + 109
4    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000100231a00 specialized specialized StaticString.withUTF8Buffer<A> ((UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) -> A) -> A + 342
5    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x000000010035f4a0 specialized _fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, file : StaticString, line : UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never + 96
6    Band Manager 2.0                   0x000000010005f500 AppDelegate.(managedObjectModel.getter).(closure #1) + 463
7    Band Manager 2.0                   0x000000010005d8d0 AppDelegate.managedObjectModel.getter + 194
8    Band Manager 2.0                   0x000000010005f880 AppDelegate.(persistentStoreCoordinator.getter).(closure #1) + 1115
9    Band Manager 2.0                   0x000000010005dad0 AppDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator.getter + 211
10   Band Manager 2.0                   0x0000000100061020 AppDelegate.(managedObjectContext.getter).(closure #1) + 35
11   Band Manager 2.0                   0x000000010005dce0 AppDelegate.managedObjectContext.getter + 211
12   Band Manager 2.0                   0x000000010005a0d0 AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching(Notification) -> () + 51
13   Band Manager 2.0                   0x000000010005d530 @objc AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching(Notification) -> () + 71
14   CoreFoundation                     0x00007fff85d1c520 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
15   CoreFoundation                     0x00007fff85d1c280 _CFXRegistrationPost + 427
16   CoreFoundation                     0x00007fff85d1c160 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
17   CoreFoundation                     0x00007fff85cd9f90 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 2018
18   CoreFoundation                     0x00007fff85cd94c0 _CFXNotificationPost + 667
19   Foundation                         0x00007fff8771a955 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
20   AppKit                             0x00007fff839439f6 -[NSApplication _postDidFinishNotification] + 297
21   AppKit                             0x00007fff839437b4 -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification] + 208
22   AppKit                             0x00007fff838069c1 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 552
23   AppKit                             0x00007fff838065a6 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 661
24   Foundation                         0x00007fff87765cfb -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 290
25   Foundation                         0x00007fff87765c31 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 102
26   AE                                 0x00007fff86b6ad06 aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 544
27   AE                                 0x00007fff86b6ac76 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) + 39
28   AE                                 0x00007fff86b6aa71 aeProcessAppleEvent + 312
29   HIToolbox                          0x00007fff85277da8 AEProcessAppleEvent + 55
30   AppKit                             0x00007fff838019c4 _DPSNextEvent + 1833
31   AppKit                             0x00007fff83f7cd72 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 2796
32   AppKit                             0x00007fff837f640d -[NSApplication run] + 926
33   AppKit                             0x00007fff837c0d09 NSApplicationMain + 1237
34   Band Manager 2.0                   0x00000001000613d0 main + 13
35   libdyld.dylib                      0x00007fff9b8ad234 start + 1
(lldb)
```

I'm hoping someone will have some insight as to how to fix this.  I'm relatively new to core data and it's brought my coding to a complete standstill as, of course, the app crashes immediately after launch.

Thanks!

UPDATE:  I should clarify, that I understand the technical reason why this is happening (not finding a resource needed) but I have no idea how to fix this.  The resource which it can't seem to find is something that was automatically generated at some point in the past.  I can't seem to figure out how to get XCODE to regenerate the needed file, or even why it went missing in the first place.

Comment: If `url(forResource` returns `nil` then the resource is missing.

Comment: That much I get... the question is... where should this resource be, and how can I replace it?  It had to be something automatically generated, because I didn't manually create it.  Since I'm still in development, I'm happy to throw away all my test data and just have XCODE recreate an empty data file from scratch to get it working again, but haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So I figured this one out...

About a week ago, I renamed the core data file to from "Band Manager_2_0" to "bmData", and for the past week everything has been working fine.  However, today, while I was migrating data, it finally "broke" the connection.

I have no idea why the connection didn't break immediately upon renaming the file, which would have clued me into the problem.  It must have cashed the location in a way that I disrupted today.

What is particularly confusing is that the code is looked for an extension of "momd", however the actual file has an extension of .xcdatamodeld... obviously something behind the scenes in XCODE 8.

Regardless, this problem has been solved.

Comment: I'm confused. So what's the solution? What fixed your problem?